# Dropdown list showing blank data

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<script>
    function loaddropdown()
    {
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("ddFAge");
        
        for(var i=1;i<=100;i++)
        {
            var newOption = new Option()
            newOption=document.createElement(option);
            newOption.Text = i;
            newOption.value = i;
            dropdown.options[i] = newOption;
            
            //dropdown.options.add(newOption);
   
            //<option value="0"><--Select Age--></option>
        }
    }
    window.onload=loaddropdown();
</script>
```

I wrote this script to bind 1-100 numbers to asp.net dropdown list. But dropdown list is not showing any data .I have attached screen shot of the drop down. What is wrong in above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code have multiple errors. Try this.

```
    function loaddropdown()
    {
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("ddFAge");
        
        for(var i=1;i<=100;i++)
        {
            var newOption = window.document.createElement('option');
            newOption.text = i;
            newOption.value = i;
            dropdown.options[i] = newOption;
        }
    }
    window.onload=loaddropdown();
```